# while loop api calls and storing response in array in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, while-loop, fetch-api

```
var allData = []

function makeRequest(){
  fetch(url)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(json){
    allData.push(...json.result)
    if (someCondition from json) {
      makeRequest()
    } 
  })
}
makeRequest();
console.log(allData)
```

The above function continuously makes api calls until a condition is met in the API response. I am hoping to append all the results from the API call in a variable called allData. Doing a console.log of allData in the above state results in an empty array. How do I wait until all the makeRequest functions are done firing and then console.logging allData?

Answer (score 0):

fetch returns a promise that will return res once its resolve. Promise is async. Try this

```
function makeRequest(){
  return fetch(url)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(json){
    allData.push(...json.result)
    if (someCondition from json) {
      return makeRequest() // return a promise to continue waiting
    } 
  })
}
makeRequest().then(function() { // waiting
  console.log(allData)
});
```